# Parallel Reading multiple XML files and inserting in database

Tags: c#, xml, task-parallel-library

As performance improvement, I want to read 10 XML files in parallel and insert data in database.

1.How to achieve reading and database insert in parallel?
i.e. when one file is reading insert data of already read XML file.

2.How to achieve processing multiple XML files(including reading and database insert) in parallel.
i.e.Processing 10 files at same time.
Language C#

```
Used Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method1(), CancellationToken.None, 
                           TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

but method inside Method1() getting called only once.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach(...)`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Even Parallel.ForEach() gives same results.Method2() which is inside Method1() is getting called only once.

Comment: so you want one thread reading the disk and the other writing to the database? use an internal queue. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If I have 19 input files then I want to process 5 files in parallel in one batch then remaining 9 files in parallel in other batch.

Comment: that's 14... what are you doing with the other 5. either way use `Parallel.ForEach` and let the computer deside the batching.

Answer (score 1):

Use standard producer/consumer pattern.

```
var xmlFiles = new BlockingCollection<XDocument>();

var readFiles = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(".", "*.xml"))
            xmlFiles.Add(XDocument.Load(file));
    }
    finally { xmlFiles.CompleteAdding(); }
});

var processFiles = Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var xml in xmlFiles.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        // Insert data to database
    }
});

Task.WaitAll(readFiles, processFiles);
```

This method provides independent reading files from disk and writing data to the database.